# android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example..AnalyticsApplication

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am new to android and in a process of adding google analytics to one of my application.
I am getting the following error when running my application.

```
android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.xxx.xxx.xxx.AnalyticsApplication
```

This is my main activity.

```
 package com.example.dell.testanalytics;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Logger;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Tracker mTracker;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
        mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

// [START screen_view_hit]
        String name = getString(R.string.test);
        Log.i(TAG, "Setting screen name: " + name);
        mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + name);
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
        // [END screen_view_hit]
        return false;
    }


}
```

The error is pointing the place I call the analytics application method.

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong since i am not getting any errors or red lines in the code.

Would be great if i could get your assistance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wish to replace the singleton `Application` instance with some subclass of `Application`, you need to have [the `android:name` attribute of the `<application>` element of your manifest point to that subclass](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm).

Comment: How do I add this if I have android:name being used already by my Acra Crash report library?

Comment: @Lion789: You can have only one custom `Application` registered in the manifest. Through inheritance and composition, you need to combine your business logic into a single `Application` subclass. ACRA does not require that you use some `Application` that they supply. So, if you have some other library that does, extend their custom `Application` subclass with your own, and do your ACRA initialization there.

Answer (score 1):

Well I believe everything answered ahead of me is true but it is more important where you place the `android:name` attribute. Do this in your manifest `<application android:name="com.yourwebsite.appname.SubApplication" >...</application>`
NOT

```
<application> android:name="com.yourwebsite.appname.SubApplication"
        ...</application>
```

Also do not add any more `<application>` tags use your original one!!

Comment: You have given the android:name="" attribute in the wrong place.